# Pandas DataFrame.rolling window with MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index, pandas-groupby

How can I apply a `DataFrame.rolling` function and assign the values back to the original DataFrame?

E.g.,

```
i = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B','C'], np.arange(1, 11, 1)], names=['Name','Num'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(30), i, columns=['Vals'])
window = df.groupby(['Name']).rolling(3, min_periods=3)
df['Window'] = window['Vals'].apply(lambda x: x[1] + x[2])
```

In this case, I want the rolling lambda to reset with each `Name` value, so `Window` would be `NaN` for the first 3 rows of each `Name`.  However, the assignment to a new column of the DataFrame at the end produces a column that is *entirely* `NaN`

The sample window lambda essentially works correctly, but I am noticing that it adds the grouped value to the MultiIndex.  Note in the following that there are *two* levels called `Name`:

```
window['Vals'].apply(lambda x: x[1] + x[2]) # Returns:
Name  Name  Num
A     A     1           NaN
            2           NaN
            3     -2.408704
            4     -3.184169
            5      0.207093
            6      1.649017
            7      0.789064
            8      0.706335
            9     -0.487192
            10    -1.625869
B     B     1           NaN
            2           NaN
            3      0.023201
            4     -0.044582
            5      0.409526
```

Am I using these methods incorrectly, or failing to do something necessary to get the `window.apply()` to align with the DataFrame?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the rolling function?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ linear combinations of preceding `Vals`.

Comment: I understand your problem. I'll try and see if I can find a solution.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ – cool, thanks.  Note that as a kludge we can call `index = index.droplevel()` on the results of the `df.groupby().rolling()...apply()`.  But since I can't understand if/when/why the extra level gets added, I'm worried that would stop working in the future.

Comment: I don't have an explanation for why the extra level is handled, but you can always just take the `.values` from the result and assign it back without any problems. `df['Window'] = window['Vals'].apply(lambda x: x[1] + x[2]).values`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ – yes, that seems like a good solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea. Swap the index level. Then unstack. Compute the rolling window. Then stack.

Swap the index level:

```
df.set_index(df.index.swaplevel(),inplace=True)
```

Unstack

```
df=df.unstack(level=1)
```

Compute the rolling window sum and restack.

```
df.rolling(3,min_periods=3).sum().stack()
```

Then swap back the index

In one go that reads as:

```
# Your setup
import pandas as pd
i = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B','C'], np.arange(1, 11, 1)], names=['Name','Num'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(30), i, columns=['Vals'])

# Idea
def swap_index(df):
    return(df.set_index(df.index.swaplevel()))
df2=swap_index(swap_index(df).unstack(level=1).rolling(3,min_periods=3).sum().stack())
```

The output is

```
In [1129]: df2
Out[1129]:
              Vals
Name Num
A    3    0.713198
B    3    1.040715
C    3    0.607588
A    4    0.992321
B    4    0.318793
C    4    0.716161
A    5    1.422214
B    5   -0.870407
C    5    0.440496
A    6   -0.496093
B    6    0.947817
C    6    0.163391
A    7    0.587050
B    7    1.594572
C    7    0.022100
A    8   -0.283013
B    8    4.316982
C    8   -0.312434
A    9    1.695324
B    9    1.100592
C    9   -0.002113
A    10   0.651203
B    10   1.077666
C    10  -0.268794
```

If you want the NaNs for 1 and 2, then you need to create an empty data frame from your original index and merge with it. That's a bit of a pain still, but maybe this already does the trick for you.